# How can I get spotlight to search everywhere for any file?

Tags: macos, catalina, spotlight, indexing

I know for a fact that a file named `1A0CFDAF-E43B-49E1-AC88-CD8CC9146947.jpeg` exists in my photo library originals/ subdirectory.  But searching for `1A0CFDAF-E43B-49E1-AC88-CD8CC9146947.jpeg` using Spotlight returns no results.

This is the kind of thing I look for, because if it were obvious I'd already know where it is.  I want to have confidence spotlight is searching everything, so that when I get "no result" I know that means "the file does not exist on your hard drive."

Is there a way to expand Spotlight's search domain so that it literally indexes my whole drive and finds any and every file, like it really kind of should?

Comment: Can I just ask how you know for a fact...?  Catalina converts your pictures library and replaces the filename with a long UUID alphanumeric string.  Your filename does not reflect this.  In Catalina the original filename is moved into the file's attributes.  Searching for a UUID string (the actual file's name) within my photo library gets a result, as long as "System files are included" in the Spotlight search.

Comment: You can expand the areas Finder searches look in by including Invisible and System files using this method: https://osxdaily.com/2014/01/30/search-system-files-included-mac-os-x/ (that shows how to search for System files; Invisible files follows the same procedure, just choose that option).

Answer (score 3):

Spotlight doesn't search hidden & system areas at all, by design.

The simplest way to get around this is to use something like [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) (freeware) instead. You might need to allow it access to Photos Library, in Privacy and Security preferences.

It doesn't index, so it's slower than Spotlight, but it will find anything, anywhere.

Comment: Does EasyFind search for the files' attributes?

Comment: Thanks!  Good idea.  I can also use the "find" command in Terminal to do a slow search of everything each time, but the point of Spotlight is supposed to be that it makes searches fast.   I guess you can either have fast or complete but not both... this is a bad design in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that may cause this issue.

1. Some locations / folders are excluded as mentioned by [Tetsujin's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378963/45492). In addition to that answer, check your `System Preferences` > `Spotlight` and see if the file in question is not excluded in the tabs `Search Results` and `Privacy`.
2. In my experience the Spotlight index goes bad relatively often for some reason. Try rebuilding it using one of these methods:

   a. Use an app like [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html)

   b. Follow the method [recommended by Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716)

   c. Issue the following commands in the terminal (most thorough method, *only for experienced users*):

   ```
   mdutil -i off /
   sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-V100
   sudo rm -rf /.Spotlight-V200
   mdutil -i on /
   mdutil -E /
   ```

Comment: If you go to `Photos Library.photoslibrary` and right click → Show package contents, you'll find a lot of files which are not indexed by default. Anything that needs "Show package contents", is excluded from Spotlight.

Comment: @ankii Just to reiterate: searching for a filename in my Photos library does yield a result, as long as "System files are inlcuded" has been selected in the Spotlight search.

Comment: @Redarm something changed in Catalina, Mojave here? I cannot find files in say deep in "masters" using spotlight. I have all checkboxes checked in Sys pref. I used Finder's attributes settings to include system files too, no effect. regarding your comment above, I searched for actual file name, let me check UUID. \\ never mind, I cannot see any UUID looking file under photoslibrary package.

Comment: @ankii "Masters" is deprecated.  It's now called "Originals" as in Rich's original post.  To be sure I opened an older library with "Masters" folder and found it removed after the Photos conversion.  All the original filenames were replaced by UUID filenames and manually searching for one and running xattr -l on the files shows the following attributes: `com.apple.assetsd.originalFilename:` with the original filename and
`com.apple.assetsd.publicGlobalUUID:` with the UUID actual filename, as attributes.  Searching for one of those UUID filenames yields results.

Comment: Sorry I have to correct myself: the publicGlobal UUID is not the same as the filename UUID.

Comment: @Redarm there is no "System files are included" in my System Preferences -> Spotlight pane.  I'm not sure what you mean by "selected in the Spotlight search".  When I do a spotlight search there are zero options to select.  Can you clarify?  Are you using Catalina?  I forgot to mention I'm on Catalina, oops.

Comment: @Rich use Finder and update search criteria. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/108969/313842

Comment: @Redarm seems like you have to know where the file is already to search using your method of xattr -l etc.  I actually have a method for finding photos in Photos' library, you "Edit in Safari" and the filename is part of the path in the path bar, but this is very specific for Photos and won't help me if I'm looking for any file named "*stringystring*" on my hard drive, don't know where to look, might be in ~/library, might be /Library, might be on my secondary drive....

Comment: @anki thanks for the Finder search tip, that seems like it will be useful to me.  It's not a complete solution but it helps!  Note that it still does not find any photos in my album, which is located on my external drive.  Spotlight is indexing that drive, which I confirmed with mdutil.

Comment: @Rich I think ankii has already shown how to include system files (similar to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326545/finder-not-searching-files-in-library-and-library/326573#326573 ).  My point about the original filename is moot, after the correction to your original post, but for the sake of argument, if I only know the original filename, I would use Terminal.  Maybe something like `find . -xattrname "com.apple.assetsd.originalFilename" -exec xattr -lr {} \; | grep "original_filename.png"`?  I'm sure there are better solutions out there.

Comment: @Redarm Thanks! I confirm that on macOS 11 Big Sur in Finder the Spotlight search parameter "System files" being set as "are included" yields results within the .photoslibrary package. I was able to combine this with "Raw Query" being `kMDItemImageDirection > 89 && kMDItemImageDirection < 181` in order to search for all photos shot with a compass orientation between East (90) and South (180).